# ViewModel that Observes another ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a DAO that returns this:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users")
 fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>>
```

I need to observe this and transform `User` objects into `People` objects. `People` does not implement or extend `User`, but I have a method that can convert them. This is a requirement I cannot change.

```
 fun convert(user: User): Person {...}
```

This is how I am trying to observe the data.

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel {
    private lateinit var people: MutableLive<List<People>>

    init {
        db.getUsers().observe(this, Observer { userList ->
            if(userList != null)
               // here I need to do some sort of transformation.
        }
    }

    // what activity will observer
    fun getPeople() : MutableLive<List<People>> {
       return people
    }
}
```

So I would love it if the `Activity` could observe the `people: MutableLive<List<People>>` and be unaware that this transformation is happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`Transformations.map`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#map) does, which in your example you could use to do something like this:

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var people: LiveData<List<Person>>

    init {
        people = Transformations.map(db.getUsers()) { users ->
            users.map { user -> convert(user) }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you a `LiveData` that's sourced by the original but applies the given mapping function to the data it emits, plus lifecycle awareness is maintained properly as well.